# UISlider and UILabel cause infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, uislider

I have the following code that creates and adds a slider and label to a view. As soon as I move the slider it gives a SIGABRT in the AppDelegate class and enters an infinite loop. I dont understand what am I doing wrong (if I only add the slider it works fine)

```
class test: UIView {   

   var value: Float

   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
      self.addSubview(getSlider())
      self.addSubview(getLabel())   
   }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      value = 0.9
      super.init(frame:frame)   
   }

   func getSlider()-> UISlider {
      let slider: UISlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(10,10,self.frame.width,30))
      slider.addTarget(self, action:"change", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
      return slider   
  }

   func getLabel()-> UILabel {
      let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,50,50,50))
      label.text = "\(value)"

      return label   
   } 

 func change(sender: UISlider) {
    value = sender.value
 }
```

Comment: invoking `-addSubview:` inside the `-drawRect:` method is not the most brilliant idea; you should put those lines into a different place in the view lifecycle, for e.g. into `-didMoveToSuperview` or `-willMoveToSuperview:` (or their Swift equivalent, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function takes a value, you need to put a `:` when you reference it.

```
slider.addTarget(self, action:"change:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't override drawRect unless you need to do some custom rendering. Move adding the subviews to the end of init.

Comment: Did that but didnt fix it. I still get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3+**

Since Swift 3+, selector declaration and implementation is changed.

```
slider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.change), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

@objc func change(sender: UISlider) {
   value = sender.value
   print("sender.value - \(sender.value)")
 }
```

Also note, remove `drawRect` from your code.